# Where is wp() function definition?

Tags: php

In WordPress source code, there is one point I can not understand. In /wp-blog-header.php, there is a call to wp() function. However, I can not find any definition for that function. How this call don't cause error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the code :).

Before calling `wp()`, `/wp-blog-header.php` loads `/wp-load.php` (which assuming you have correctly installed WordPress) loads `/wp-config.php`. At the bottom of that file, it calls `/wp-settings.php`.

This file loads a lot of other files, initialising the core parts of WordPress. Amongst them, is the `wp-includes/functions.php` file. It's inside this file that `wp()` is defined.

Once `/wp-settings.php` has finished loading all the files, `wp()` is then called - this 'starts' WordPress (interpreting the incoming url, processing it into a query, choosing a template and finally outputting the content and sending into the user.

Comment: I'm new to wordpress, I want to know the behaviour or we can say Role of wp() function in wordpress. 
Can you please put some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can see info about [the wp() function](http://queryposts.com/function/wp/) on queryposts.com which also links to [the function on trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L1568). I also learned a surprising amount from Nacin's powerpoint slides from ["You Don't Know Query"](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012) that discussion the `wp()` function starting on slide 29.

Comment: @tight slideshow! bookmarked.